# Node.js design: multiple async functions writing to database using function passed as a closure

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, concurrency, closures

I am writing a standalone web scraper in Node, run from command line, which looks for specific data on a set of pages, fetches page views data from Google Analytics and saves it all in an MySQL database. Almost all is ready, but today I found a problem with the way I write data in the db.

To make thing easier let's assume I have an `index.js` file and two controllers - `db` and `web`. `Db` reads/writes data to db, `web` scraps the pages using configurable amount of PhantomJs instances.

Web exposes one function `checkTargetUrls(urls, writer)`
where `urls` is an array with urls to be checked and `writer` is an optional parameter, called only if it is a function and there is data to be written.

Now the way I pass the writer is obviously wrong, but looks as follows (in `index.js`):

```
some code here
....
let pageId = 0;
... some promises code,
which checks validy of urls, 
creates new execution in the database, etc.
...

.then(ulrs => {
     return web.checkTargetUrls(urls,

        function(singleUrl, pageData) {
        ...
        a chain of promisable functions from db controller,
        which first lookup page id in the db, then its
        puts in the pageId variable and continues with write to db
        ...

}).then(() => {

logger.info('All done captain!');
}).catch(err => {logger.error(err})
```

In the effect randomly `pageId` gets overwritten by id of preceeding/succeeding page and invalid data is saved. Inside `web` there are up to 10 concurrent instances of PhantomJs running, which call `writer` function after they analyzed a page. Excuse me my language, but for me an analogy for that situation would be if I had, say, 10 instances of some object, which then rely for writing on a singleton, which causes the `pageId` overwriting problem (don't know how to properly express in JS/Node.js terms).

So far I have found one fix to the problem, but it is ugly as it introduces tight coupling. If I put the `writer` code in a separate module and then load it directly from inside the `web` controller all works great. But for me it is a bad design pattern and would rather do it otherwise.

```
var writer = require('./writer');

function checkTargetUrls(urls, executionId) {

return new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {

        let poolSize = config.phantomJs.concurrentInstances;
        let running = 0;

        ....
        a bit of code goes here
        ....
        if (slots != undefined && slots != null && slots.data.length > 0) {

           return writer.write(executionId, singleUrl, slots);
         }
         ...
         more code follows
})
}
```

I have a hard time findng  a nicer solution, where I could still pass `writer` as an argument for `checkTargetUrls(urls, writer)` function. Can anyone point me in the right direction or suggest where to look for the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The exact problem around your global pageId is not entirely clear to me but you could reduce coupling by exposing a setWriter function from your 'web' controller.

```
var writer;
module.exports.setWriter = function(_writer) { writer = _writer };
```

Then near the top of your index.js, something like:

```
var web = require('./web');
web.setWriter(require('./writer'));
```

Comment: Yes, I could have done that, but taking a shower helped to resolve the problem better ;-)

The thing was the pageId wasn't scoped properly and was placed in the part of the code, which was executed as a 'single thread'. Moving it inside the body of the 'writer' function solved the overwriting issue.